# Once dataflow job is created in Google Cloud using apache beam sdk, can we delete the tmp files from cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Dataflow job has been created to store the logs details from google dialogflow to big query
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow jobs do not depend on any **temporary files** once the job has been stopped. However, deleting the temporary files of a running job would cause problems.

Therefore, I recommend the following. If you do not have any **dataflow job running** that are using a particular **GCS location** for **storing temporary files**,you can **delete all the temp files** in that GCS location to avoid costs. 
If you have any **dataflow jobs that are still running, do not delete any of the temporary files** in their GCS temp files location. If you do not wish to manually delete files, you can use an object lifecycle policy to move those temporary files once the dataflow stops.

Comment: Thanks for your input. files are related to stopped dataflow jobs as well as running one. However as per my understanding those tmp files are not having any impact on running one once the dataflow job is created. we need to setup lifecycle policy hence checking for same. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Whether the files are actually not used or not after job startup depends on Dataflow runtime (which could change). All temp files should be cleaned up once the Dataflow job finishes.

Comment: @SRN In general it's not recommended to delete temp files for a running job. As mentioned by *@chamikara* the impact of temp files totally depends on runtime. It will also depend on how the pipeline has been written.Specially If you are using some job templates and you don't know how the flow is working then its better not tamper temp files until the job stops.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya - The job will run continuously since its purpose is to store the dialogflow daily interaction details to the bigquery. thanks for explanation, we won't be setting any policy for those files for now.

Comment: @chamikara - Thanks for your explanation. It's better to not delete temp files associated with the running job.

Comment: @SRN Since your doubt has been cleared ,now if you accept the answer it will be helpful for the community for future reference.